# In MS excel is there a way to combine a custom data column to a exiting pivot table

Tags: excel

I have a pivot table created using an external data source. I want to have a custom column where I can enter some data manually against the selected records. I used the method PivotTable Analyse>Convert to formula and have a custom column , but every time the pivot table is updated with new or removed information the custom column data is not correctly represented.

My Requirement is collect the data from an external source , then combine that with some custom data for each records and then create a table that I can use in another application.Or within excel as a report

Comment: I'd suggest using Power Query to import your data and add the column.  You can then output it to a Pivot Table Report or Chart.  When you refresh, everything should update.

Comment: Yes, but how can I mearge my custom data. I could add a custom column and add them but, I want this custom data entry to be somewhat user friendly. not open the query editor every time I wan to add or adjust the custom data

Comment: Add the data to a table/database/or other defined structure, and reference that in your query. If that suggestion does not provide you sufficient information, I suggest you read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then edit your question to help us help you.